# Driving a 24 V isolated load from a 3.3 V MCU

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, 3.3v

I am looking to drive a 12-24 V purely resistive load from a 3.3 V MCU. I would like to use an opto-isolator to separate the circuits electrically.

I've drawn up the following circuit, but I'm not sure about exactly how to simulate it in CircuitLab. Can someone please tell me if the following circuit will work for my needs, or what changes I need to consider?

My concern with driving the MOSFET is that its V<sub>GS(max)</sub> voltage is 20 V, so I've put a voltage divider to limit it to ~10 V when the opto-isolator turns on. I know I can use a MOSFET with a higher V<sub>GS(max)</sub>, but I couldn't find any with the package size of the FDMC0310AS.

EDITED:

Original Image:

[image]

Modified Circuit:

[image]

Comment: You should omit R13, in parallel with the opto's LED - it just adds an extra load on the MCU output.

Comment: Re: "I'm not sure about exactly how to simulate it in circuitlab" I'd say forget about that websim and try any of the [free SPICE-based simulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_electronics_circuit_simulators) that run on your own computer. Almost all big IC manufacturers give a SPICE-based simulator [for free now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE#Adoption).

Comment: FYI, here is a [fairly introductory (but not just utterly basic) note](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF) to using MOSFETs. There is actually no small number of more advanced documents on the web, but they usually are overwhelming for the beginner. A good 2nd read is http://www.radio-sensors.se/download/gate-driver2.pdf (That one was a TI note/seminar SLUP169 at one point, but it seems it's not on their site anymore for some reason). Hope this helps.

Comment: Since your load is resistive you can *mostly* ignore transients and just check that at on and off steady state none of the datasheet limitations are exceeded. I like to play it safe and always include a flyback diode from drain to the positive rail. Even a resistive load will likely have a bit of inductance.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly like your circuit, but the center of the voltage divider is being driven instead of the end, which will drive the load (R4) with nice snappy edges.

Be aware that when the MCU's output is low the load will be hot, so in order to start with the load cold the MCU's output must be high on power-up.

[image]

and here's the LTspice circuit list if you want to play with the circuit.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1576 736
WIRE 656 0 560 0
WIRE 784 0 656 0
WIRE 656 32 656 0
WIRE 784 32 784 0
WIRE 784 144 784 112
WIRE 128 208 96 208
WIRE 256 208 208 208
WIRE 656 208 656 112
WIRE 656 208 448 208
WIRE 656 224 656 208
WIRE 736 224 656 224
WIRE 96 304 96 208
WIRE 256 304 192 304
WIRE 480 304 448 304
WIRE 560 304 560 0
WIRE 656 304 656 224
WIRE 96 416 96 384
WIRE 192 416 192 304
WIRE 192 416 96 416
WIRE 288 416 192 416
WIRE 480 416 480 304
WIRE 480 416 368 416
WIRE 496 416 480 416
WIRE 560 416 560 384
WIRE 560 416 496 416
WIRE 656 416 656 384
WIRE 656 416 560 416
WIRE 784 416 784 240
WIRE 784 416 656 416
WIRE 496 464 496 416
FLAG 496 464 0
SYMBOL nmos 736 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value FDMC8462
SYMBOL voltage 560 288 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 24
SYMBOL voltage 96 288 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(3.3 0 100u0 1u 1u 100u 500u)
SYMBOL res 768 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2.4
SYMBOL res 224 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 75
SYMBOL res 640 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL res 640 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL Optos\\PC817A 352 256 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res 384 400 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rsim
SYMATTR Value 1G
TEXT 502 440 Left 2 !.tran 1000u uic
```

Comment: And again, charging the gate with high resistance. And discharging unknown cpapacitance with unknown current through optocoupler. Right, burn both of them, why only risk one component?

Comment: I see. Playing fast and loose is better than perusing the data sheets and running the simulation?

Comment: Whatever (15 characters)

Comment: Kudos for putting this into a sim (although really that's the OP's job for a circuit of this level). I'm curious if it's you who -1'd me or someone else (Gregory). I'd be glad to take on board any criticism regarding what I said; especially from someone more experienced, as you are.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: Thanks for the kudos. :)  I didn't -1 you since I'd rather critique a post than just downvoting it. Kornblum's MMV. ;)

Comment: Regarding the potential damage to the opto... Your simulation shows a peak current of 35mA through the collector, which is below the 50mA rating of the PC817. The LTspice model for FDMC8462 has a gate charge of 15nC. However the datasheet for that indicates a max of 43nC; 15nC is the typical value given for Vgs under 4.5V (you're driving the gate to 12V). Also the FDMC0310AS (OP's choice) has a slightly higher 52nC max charge in its datasheet. I picked a IRFH5110 in the simulation instead (gate charge 48nC). It doesn't seem to make any difference though in terms of peak current.

Comment: I'm not sure what the dominant resistance here is damping the discharge. IRFH5110 and FDMC8462 have very similar Rg (1.5 and respectively 1 ohm) in LTspice. I [yet] don't know however how to estimate the dynamic CE resistance of the PC817.

Comment: If I pick an IRF7335, which has a Qgate of 13nC and an Rg of 3 ohms (in LTspice), then I get a slightly lower peak of 33mA. So Rg does seem to matter, but only a little. The opto appears to be the main damping element.

Comment: @SudoKill: Also, in EM Field's circuit you can safely replace the bottom resistor in the divider with a 12V Zener (I've tried it). Here the replacement works because the opto is the main sink of current when it saturates. You'll actually get nicer/sharper gate edges that way... well with the IRF7335 anyhow. Withe the FDMC8462 it fails to converge with a Zener, I'm guessing because the edges are too sharp. http://imgur.com/INUju9t

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: You can determine the opto's dynamic CE resistance by looking at the slope of voltage across the CE versus the current through it and then doing \$ R = \frac{E}{I} \$.  I agree that the opto seems to be the main damping element, and the best way to minimize the damping - I believe -  is to use an opto with a high CTR and a low CE ON resistance at the desired working current.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've done that. http://imgur.com/YBVjwD0 I have no idea how accurate that might be though (compared to real-life).