# Pump does not get enough current via MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to build the v4.3 circuit described here: [Will this schematic work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182896/will-this-schematic-work)

[image: Updated Schematic v4.3]

I am building just one branch out of the decoder IC to test on a breadboard. Component info is as follows:

1. The optocoupler is PC817 i.s.o TLP621;
2. The MOSFET is IRF630B;
3. The flyback diode is 6A4;
4. The resistor between MOSFET gate and ground is 5.2K;
5. The peak power rating of the pump is 2.7A @12V.

Now when power is on, RasPi is up and the input to the decoder is set correctly, the pump does not work.

I tried the following to troubleshoot,

1. Connected the pump directly to 12V input, it works. Connected a multimeter in series and found the current draw to be approx 3A to start and then dropping down to 1.8A;
2. Connected an LED via a suitable resistor across the output side of the optocoupler (no mosfet/pump) and it turns on and off depending upon logic input to the decoder;
3. Removed LED and measured the voltage across the output side of the opto-coupler to be ~12V;
4. Added the mosfet and measured the voltage across the drain and source with correct logic input to decoder. This measured ~11-12V;
5. Added pump (w/o flyback diode). Now with correct logic input to decoder, it does not work;
6. Connected a multimeter (in current reading mode) in series between the cathode of the pump and drain. It measures only 0.63A;
7. Replace the pump with LED and proper resistor and enable the decoder, the LED lights up.

It appears to me that connecting the pump via the MOSFET somehow impedes the current flow to a great extent even when it is biased according to specs.

I thought that the MOSFET in question is a voltage controlled device. So when a proper \$V_{gs}\$ is applied, it should simply conduct the current required by the load.

Why does it conduct only 0.63A when the starting current requirement is around 3A? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What Vgs of the MOSFET can/did you measure?

Comment: Breadboards are not designed for carrying currents of that magnitude. Try soldering the cables for the pump to the MOSFET and power supply directly.

Comment: I doubt that's the main reason though. For the breadboard to drop the current to about 1/5, it would have to have a lot of resistance (around 15 ohms), and would have started to smoke with 10W dissipation.

Comment: I assume you have a heatsink on your FET ? 36watts is enough to damage it. Also try checking the FET with the diode checker on your Multimeter and make sure it still functions and you have your pin orientation right.

Comment: Also your circuit is a rather bad way use the opto to drive a MOSFET. I suggest you take inspiration from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/193643/54580 But you need to use a MOSFET that turns on at round 5V for that (i.e. about half-way from the 12V rail.) Yours only turns on at 10V Vgs.

Comment: This is what your driving looks like http://imgur.com/r5WNnzZ Rather terrible, but should sorta work. I've used the model from IR.

Comment: @CharlieHanson, step 1 in my original post was done using the breadboard, so I dont think thats the issue here.

Comment: @BenG, yes the FET has a heatsink, it does not get hot and it still is able to drive an LED

Comment: @Respawned Fluff, Iam a hobbyist trying to learn. Can you explain why it is a bad way? How is the circuit in you sim different than mine save for the Rsim resistor? As you already may have sensed, my intention was to isolate the RasPi from the pump.

Comment: @Respawned Fluff, also currently I can't source an alternate mosfet and have to make do with IRF630B.

Comment: That one is not different, that one is basically your circuit. The one from the other question/thread is different though, faster. Faster driving is better for the survivability of the MOSFET.

Comment: Since the important part regarding debugging might have gotten lost in all these comments, you need to measure (and report here) Vgs when your MOSFET turns on, even if it's just letting through only those 0.6A. (That was my first comment.)

Comment: @Respawned Fluff, well save for the Rsim (whose purpose is not clear to me). But my issue is that this circuit does not work and I can't seem to figure out why..maybe I ought to try adding the  Rsim??

Comment: No, Rsim is just used for simulation convergence purposes (it's a 1Gigaohm resistor). Basically you can't have the two parts of the circuit completely unconnected (i.e. just optically) in SPICE.

Comment: Ok, I connected my multimeter directly across the mosfet before & after the 5.2K resistor. Assuming Iam measuring Vgs correctly and with the decoder enabled, I see that Vgs starts at 10.68v and slowly rises to 11.25. I stopped there because I could sense that the mosfet has become very hot. My apologies to @BenG, I wasnt looking close enough the last time.

Comment: No drama. You're not a EE until you have a to-220 scar :)

Comment: seems like you cant respond with just a smiley! :)

Comment: @BenG, but seriously the IRF630B spec sheet figures for power dissipation mention max limit of 72 watts. Even with a little bit of derating, I dont see why it should not be able to handle 36w? Any explanation would be helpful...

Comment: True. but that relies on a heatsink. which has it's own thermal characteristics. Do you know the rating of your heatsink? or a link to it's datasheet?

Comment: No, I just googled the product number etched on the mosfet and opened the first one that I could find. Given the prominent "F" (also etched) I assumed that it was the Fairchild brand. As I mentioned earlier in the thread, Iam new to EE (comp sci background), so am trying to learn as I go. Does a "Fairchild IRF630B" come with different heatsink packaging options?

Comment: It might have  slightly different thermal characteristics. But heatsinks vary dramatically.  For example for a prototype I built recently a started with a heatsink that dissipated 6 watts and swapped it for one that could handle 20 watts. So do you have details on your heatsink? eg degrees/watt?

Comment: @BenG, unfortunately no.

Comment: Well. There is no standard value as far as I know so you could either use direct measuremrnt uf your DMM does temp. Or troll the supplier websites looking for a matching picture. But be prepared to replace your FET :) I'd be inclined to source a heatsink with a good thermal figure to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Step (3)after edits. If there's 12V across the opto output, there's about 0V across the 5K gate resistor and the FET is OFF...

Try again with the optocoupler ON (probably 10mA through its LED. max 2V across the opto, so that Vgs=10V and the FET turns on.

Comment: Phototransistor current will be limited to about 2.5mA because of the 4.7K resistor. That will cause the MOSFET to turn on rather slowly so there's risk of burning it, but it should turn on... eventually.

Comment: Yeah but he's saying there's practically no photocurrent (12V across the opto output), not 2.5mA. If that's so, the problem lies earlier.

Comment: Who knows? He says "Connected an LED via a suitable resistor across the output side of the optocoupler (no mosfet/pump) and it turns on and off depending upon logic input to the decoder; Removed LED and measured the voltage across the output side of the opto-coupler to be ~12V;" I didn't exactly grok what he measured there (was the driving signal on or off?) He seems to have enough current to light up a LED on the opto's phototransitor side.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your freewheel diode .It protects the mosfet from voltage spikes at turnoff.Use a logic level fet or anything that is properly specified at lower Vgs .Substitute a lower RDS on fet which will be easy to find for VDs of say 50Volt.